# Getting this jquery error on homepage of my Magento store

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, javascript, jquery

Can anyone help? Seems to be a jquery issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a jquery error. Perhaps some widget being used on this home page is trying to load content from a different domain. Browser blocks accessing contents of iframe with a different domain. This might be helpful. Let me know. Or you can probably delete the widget